# How to skip errors in a loop for Julia

Tags: julia

I want to skip an error during a loop in julia. The example is below. I want to calculate square root of each element in a vector. Since sqrt(-16) is a complex value, Julia will report error and stop the loop. I would like julia to continue the loop when there is an error in the loop. The output I am looking for is that result = [1, 2, 3, 99999, 5, 6] where 99999 indicates there is an error.

```
vec = [1,4,9,-16,25,36]
result = zeros(6)
for i = 1:6
  result[i] = sqrt(vec[i])
end
```

Comment: `99999` seems like an odd value to use, especially since it's a valid output of `sqrt`. Have you considered using `missing` or `nothing` instead, or perhaps `-1`, since that value is outside the output domain? Basically the same as @Mason said, btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [`try`/`catch`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#try) will intercept the error. Within the `catch` block, you can discard the error and return the sentinel value:

```
vec = [1,4,9,-16,25,36]
result = zeros(6)
for i = 1:6
    result[i] = try
        sqrt(vec[i])
    catch
        999999
    end
end
```

I assume this is a toy example. I will reiterate [Julia's style guide](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.2/manual/style-guide/#Don't-overuse-try-catch-1): its best to avoid the error in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answer which uses `try / catch` in the spirit of your question, you have a few more options. Probably the best approach would be:

```
function mysqrt(x)
    if x < 0
        999999.0
    else
        sqrt(x)
    end
end

vec = [1,4,9,-16,25,36]

julia> mysqrt.(vec)
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
      1.0
      2.0
      3.0
 999999.0
      5.0
      6.0
```

Though I would strongly suggest you not use `999999.0` as your sentinel value but instead use `NaN` or `missing`.

Another option available to you would be to lift `vec` to a `Vector{Complex}` so that you don't run into domain errors, but this will come at a performance cost. That would look like

```
julia> sqrt.(complex(vec))
6-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
 1.0 + 0.0im
 2.0 + 0.0im
 3.0 + 0.0im
 0.0 + 4.0im
 5.0 + 0.0im
 6.0 + 0.0im
```

and then you can filter the vector by real and imaginary parts as you wish.